# Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

Working on a project and I can not figure out why i am getting an:

```
overlay.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null at submitClick (overlay.js:71) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:102)
```

The code has no problem with getting the value of the first checkbox `(y.checked === true)` and placing the textContent on the index.html page when the submit button is clicked but the second `(c.checked === true)` throws an uncaught TypeError and does not place it on the webpage.

I have tried `window.onload` but that did not fix the issue.

Not sure if it matters but this is in a modal that opens up from the index.html page when a button is clicked.

I'm fairly new to coding so there is probably something obvious I am missing.

```
function submitClick() {

        let yesOrNo = document.getElementById('concept');
        let circle = document.getElementById('circle-text');
        let c = document.getElementById('stick');
  
      
        let y = document.getElementById('yes');
        let n = document.getElementById('no');
        

        if (y.checked === true) {
          yesOrNo.textContent = 'Accept';
        } else if (n.checked === true) {
          yesOrNo.textContent = 'Avoid';
        } else {
          yesOrNo.textContent = "I'm confused";
        }

        if (c.checked === true ) {
            circle.textContent = 'Likely';
            console.log(c.value);
          } else {
            circle.textContent = "Unlikely";
          }
        };
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: Either y, n, or c are null/undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    let y = document.getElementById('yes');
    let n = document.getElementById('no');
    let yesOrNo = document.getElementById('concept');

    if (y.checked === true && n.checked === true) {
        yesOrNo.innerText = "I'm confused";
    } else if (n.checked === true) {
        yesOrNo.innerText = 'Avoid';
    } else {
        yesOrNo.textContent = 'Accept';
    }

    let c = document.getElementById('stick');
    let circle = document.getElementById('circle-text');
    
    if (c.checked === true ) {
        circle.innerText = 'Likely';
    } else {
        circle.innerText = "Unlikely";
    }
})
```

```html
<form>
Yes : <input type="checkbox" id='yes' name='YesNo'><br>
No : <input type="checkbox" id='no' name='YesNo'>
<div id="concept"></div>

<hr>

stick : <input type="radio" id='stick'>
<div id="circle-text"></div>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thankas. I will give this a try